always #delay begin vs. always begin #delay
Waveform picture
Why is the value of a = 1 but y = 0 at 35ns? What is the difference between always begin #delay block and always #delay begin block?
module tb;
reg y;
reg a;
//$monitor("time = %t, a = %d", $time, a);  
  
always begin 
  #5 a = ~a; 
end

initial begin 
  a = 0; 
  #50; $finish; 
end
 
always #7 begin
  y = a;
end
 
initial begin
  $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
  $dumpvars(0, tb);
end
endmodule



You have a Verilog simulation race condition in your code.  You are trying to assign y to the value of a at the time a changes at time 35ns.  The simulator is not guaranteed to assign 0 or 1 to y.  It can choose either value and be compliant with the IEEE Std 1800-2023.  The simulator chooses to assign 0.
Your code does not adhere to recommended coding practices.  When you don't use good coding practices, you can end up with simulation results that you don't understand.

This explanation should help explain the difference (none).
#delay in front of procedural statement is procedural delay control. It is not a statement by itself.
#50; $finish;

The above is two procedural statements, the first is a null statement with a delay control, followed by the $finish statement. It would make a difference if you had
if (cond) #50; $finish; // the finish is unconditional 
if (cond) #50  $finish; // the finish is conditional 

There would also be a difference here
initial fork
  #50; $finish;
  #70  $finish;
join

The above forks three processes. One of them is a $finish with no delay. So the simulation would end immediately upon encountering the fork.
Now wherever you are allowed one statement, you can enclose that statement with a begin/end compound statement enclosure. That enclosure allows multiple statements to be place where the syntax allows one statement, and they are executed serially.
initial fork
  begin #50; $finish; end
  #70  $finish;
join

Now the fork/join only creates two processes and the first $finish comes at after a delay of 50.
initial fork
  #10 begin #50; $finish; end
  #70  $finish;
join

The $finish now comes at time 60.
Since a begin/end is considered a single statement, it too can have procedural delays placed in front of it.
Finally, getting back to your original question, initial and alwaysprocedural processes accept a single statement. You need to usebegin/endorfork/join` to have multiple statements.
always #5; a = ~a;

This is illegal because a = ~a is not associated with any process. You could write this as any of the following
always #5 a = ~a;            // a single statement.
always begin #5; a = ~a; end // two statements inside begin/end
always begin #5 a = ~a; end. // one statement inside begin/end
always #5 begin a = ~a; end. // one statement inside begin/end
always #2 begin #1; #2 a = ~a; end. // one statement inside begin/end

BTW, All of the above applies to event controls as well as delay controls, so the following are all describing equivalent behavior.
always @(posdege clk) q <= d;
always @(posdege clk) begin q <= d end;
always begin @(posdege clk) q <= d end;
always begin
   @(posdege clk) ; 
   q <= d 
end;

Your code has a race condition because one process is reading a at the same time another process is reading using a blocking assignment.

I've tested using Icarus Verilog 10.3 two files, which differ in the block:
always #7 begin
  y = a;
end

and
always begin
  #7 y = a;
end

The iverilog vvp outputs for both files differ only in the internal IDs. So the resulting waveforms does not differ.
The y value at 35ns is the previous a value (at previous tick). This's the expected behavior.

It is a race condition.  The result is expected, but it is not guaranteed.
